# KDE: shortcut to screenshot directly to clipboard

Tags: kde, clipboard

I'm looking for a way to put a rectangular screenshot directly (IE, without GUI interaction) into the clipboard -- it's a feature I used several times a day back in my bad old days with Gnome, but Spectacle has nothing like it.

I'm not above scripting it, and I've seen a couple of references to [using xclip](https://www.reddit.com/r/kde/comments/5i4awm/how_to_make_spectacle_copy_to_clipboard_by_default/db5qent/). Unfortunately, I've probably got an hour into trying this, and it simply doesn't work for me.

- Does the xclip method work for you in a modern KDE?
- gnome-screenshot doesn't work for me in KDE. Spectacle lacks the functionality I need. Is there another KDE-compatible clipboard app that you can recommend that will do this?

Comment: Okay, it seems that my answer isn't adequate. I'm deleting it.

Comment: @DKBose, it was a reasonable answer, and would be useful for others.  I couldn't accept it because it didn't actually work for me.  Thanks for your input, I will play with maim.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had lots of [discussion and comments on the KDE sub on reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/kde/comments/9kv0bz/screenshot_directly_to_clipboard/).

The final choice involved maim, xclip, and klipper config.

After unsetting Klipper's option to "ignore images," the standard xclip instructions appear to work.  Of the many screenshot options suggested, `maim` has the best options and requires only two clicks (and no keyboard) to make a rectangular selection.  My final command looks like:

`maim -s /tmp/ss.png && xclip -sel clip -t image/png -i /tmp/ss.png`

A big part of my problem was that I was testing with thunderbird, which doesn't (seem to) comprehend image/png clipboards.  If you want thunderbird to work, you need to clip it as `-t text/html`, thus:

```
echo "<img src='data:image/png;base64,"$(base64 -w0 "/tmp/ss.png")"' />" \
| xclip -selection clipboard -t text/html -i
```

Answer (score 0):

I also missed the convenient clipboard screenshotting from GNOME. I found [`KDE-Region-Screenshot`](https://github.com/cheald/KDE-Region-Screenshot) which exposes commands that use `xclip` and `spectacle` under the hood to copy directly to clipboard:

```
screenshot.sh -f  # Fullscreen
screenshot.sh -r  # Selectable region
screenshot.sh -a  # Active window
```

You can add global key shortcuts for these via the "Custom Shortcuts" menu in "System Settings".

Note that currently, it's impossible to add a shortcut for `Ctrl+Alt+PrtScrn` for screenshotting "Active Window", see https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=386253